# how to get specific text data with space and next line from xml using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to get data text from below frame data.

xml input

```
<frame name="ENUMERATION LIST" type="" version="0">
 <data><![CDATA[0:  OFF
1:  ACCESSORY
2:  RUN
3:  START_Request]]></data>
 </frame>
```

I am looking for out as given below

```
      <ELEMENTS>
        <SW-BASE-TYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>OFF</SHORT-NAME>
        </SW-BASE-TYPE>
        <SW-BASE-TYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>ACCESSORY</SHORT-NAME>
        </SW-BASE-TYPE>
        <SW-BASE-TYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>RUN</SHORT-NAME>
        </SW-BASE-TYPE>
        <SW-BASE-TYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>START_Request</SHORT-NAME>
        </SW-BASE-TYPE>
       </ELEMENTS>
```

can anyone help me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Use `analyze-string`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="data">
  <ELEMENTS>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[0-9]+:\s*(.+)">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <SW-BASE-TYPE>
          <SHORT-NAME>
            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
          </SHORT-NAME>
        </SW-BASE-TYPE>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </ELEMENTS>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```